# What do these specific letters refer to in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Apologies if this has been asked before but its rather hard to phrase and therefore search for.

I am using and learning the Jquery UI api, when I look at the code its made up from I am confused as to what these specific letters refer to.

**Example Code:**

```
           _suggest: function(t) {
                var n = this.menu.element.empty();
                this._renderMenu(n, t), this.menu.refresh(), n.show(), this._resizeMenu(), n.position(e.extend({
                    of: this.element
                }, this.options.position)), this.options.autoFocus && this.menu.next()
            },
            _resizeMenu: function() {
                var e = this.menu.element;
                e.outerWidth(Math.max(e.width("").outerWidth() + 1, this.element.outerWidth()))
            },
            _renderMenu: function(t, n) {
                var r = this;
                e.each(n, function(e, n) {
                    r._renderItemData(t, n)
                })
            },
            _renderItemData: function(e, t) {
                return this._renderItem(e, t).data("ui-autocomplete-item", t)
            },
            _renderItem: function(t, n) {
                if(n.label.includes("Entry")){
                    return e("<li>").append(e("<a style='color: #e74c3c;'>").text(n.label)).prependTo(t)
                } else {
                    return e("<li>").append(e("<a>").text(n.label)).appendTo(t)
                }
            },
```

This is just some of the code that makes up the API, now I understand that in the () brackets next to the word function are parameters (unless I'm wrong about that to).

But What do the specific letters t, n, e represent?.

**What I think is the answer**

Based on the context of the function for example _renderItem function, it has t,n passed to it, I'm guessing the t is the "term" that's been searched for, and the "e" represents an element?

I know this is probably very basic stuff but I can't seem to find any clear specific answers on this.

**So in short:** What do - t, n, e, a, i represent?

Comment: Apologise I mean what do they represent in the context of the jquery UI autocomplete functions, like in the code sample above. Sorry I didn't really make that very clear in my question! I understand that they are arguments being passed through, and that the results of one function can be passed through as parameters to inner functions but I'm not sure what they represent in jquery ui autocomplete function.

Comment: basically most of the javascript libraries use minifier to change the code to a smaller sized file so that there won't be passing a lot of data on the network when they are requested, so these `t, n, e, a, i` these can represent any function/variable/object that the librabry owner has written, it will definitely vary between libraries and even between versions of same library

Comment: Check the jQuery UI source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/77c8a85e6f23642de03cf0ea1c4310bd0450a9f2/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest referring un-minified code. This is the minified code where the variables names are shortened. Check below code:

[image]

Reference: http://piwigo.org/dev/browser/trunk/themes/default/js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?rev=28500

This should answer your question.

Comment: This gird sir or madam is FANTASTIC. I didn't know you could get uniminified versions of code! Is this possible with other libraries or has this just been done specifically for this library by whoever wrote that article? If I could upvote you twice I would. Thank you again.

Comment: @DinleyHob It can be done with each and every library. You can minify the actual code but the reverse might not be beneficial in all cases. But the providers, i.e jquery hosts both versions.

Comment: Please do _not_ use images of code. "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)"

Comment: @theTinMan The post does not require the code. It only needed a reference to the actual code. Posting the only URL would have gone against the answer rules.

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid for asking this question its starting me right in the face, they are clearly defined in the sample code I provided,

**For Example:**

```
var e = this.menu.element;
```

Sorry for wasting anyone's time with this! Let this be a monument to anyone who doesn't read before they post!